# find/replace in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that I want to use every month, but the table it will point to will change slightly. I want to use a function analogous to find/replace to just update a portion of the table names referenced. Each table will just change its name by the Month_Year for the file. I have tried a local variable with declare/set and it does not work. This is what I would like to do...

```
declare @file_name varchar(max)
SET @file_name = 'oct_16' --set as month_year used in table name

alter table sp_panel_@file_name
add LFDOB varchar(max)
```

Comment: You need to re-evaluate your database design such that this isn't necessary. Creating a new table for each month is poor design except in some very, very specific niche cases.

Comment: Despite the problem @alroc mentioned, you can create that text based on the current date if that helps, instead of having to modify a query or SP every month.

Comment: Please describe the underlying conditions or motivation you imagine are driving this requirement, as it is almost certainly the case that they can be addressed with a more appropriate database schema that does not require renaming of tables.

Comment: I have data sources that cannot easily be automated into SQL. I have a monthly file that comes from an insurance company in an excel binary worksheet, other outputs from sharepoint. I then merge all the information to do productivity reporting. I am going to ask for the file to be sent in text format, which will greatly help in automating the process.

Comment: +1000 to what @alroc said. I would add that even in those niche cases it is still most likely a horrible design. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need dynamic query

```
exec ('alter table sp_panel_+'@file_name+' add LFDOB varchar(max)')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized there is an actual "find/replace" function within SQL. It will do the trick until we can fully automate